# Check rights on directory in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

How can I know if I have rights on directory using query in Oracle??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are talking about an Oracle directory object (`CREATE DIRECTORY ...`),

```
SELECT grantee, table_name directory_name, privilege
  FROM dba_tab_privs
 WHERE table_name = <<directory name>>
```

Note that if you don't have access to the `DBA_*` tables, you can use `ALL_TAB_PRIVS` or `USER_TAB_PRIVS` instead.

If you are talking about an operating system directory, you'd need to create an Oracle directory object that corresponds to the operating system directory.  You could then use the UTL_FILE package's [FOPEN](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_file.htm#i1003526) method to try to open a file in the directory.  If it succeeds, you have permission to the directory.  Otherwise, you'll catch an exception.

Comment: Actually I have oracle client installed on my system and I would like to create directory on my local system from where I can write/read files.Is that possible in oracle.To be more specific I am using SQL Navigator to connect to Oracle Server(10 g)

Comment: @SouraM - No.  PL/SQL running on the database cannot normally write to a file on the client machine-- that would be a huge security hole.  If you were to mount a directory on your client machine from the server, it could be made to work, but that is an exceptionally unusual setup.    It would make far more sense to write a file on the database server and transfer it to your client machine or to run an application on your client machine that queries the database and writes a file.

Answer (score 1):

select * from dba_tab_privs where table_name = 'your_directory'